# Is there any possibilities to convert `FileInfo` to `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`

Tags: c#

Is there any possibilities to convert `FileInfo` to `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` as I need to send `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` as a parameter to external library?

```
var latestFile = new DirectoryInfo(filePath).EnumerateFiles(fileType).Select(fl =>
    {
        fl.Refresh();
        return fl;
    }).OrderByDescending(fi => fi.LastWriteTimeUtc).FirstOrDefault();

IEnumerable<FileInfo> Y = latestFile;
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need an immediate `FileInfo.Refresh` when you use `EnumerateFiles`? That looks weird as if you don't trust `EnumerateFiles`

Comment: the code example I put here requires `referesh`. I agree it's not required with most of the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an array, and that will be an enumerable :

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> Y = new [] { latestFile };
```

Or use `Take(1)` instead on `FirstOrDefault`

```
var latestFile = new DirectoryInfo(filePath).EnumerateFiles(fileType).Select(fl =>
                {
                    fl.Refresh();
                    return fl;
                }).OrderByDescending(fi => fi.LastWriteTimeUtc).Take(1);
```

Comment: oh, I like the simplicity of the `Take(1)` approach

Comment: `.Take(1)` is superb!

Answer (score 7):

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> Y = new[] { latestFile };
```

or just (if you're happy for the variable to be typed as an array)

```
var Y = new[] { latestFile };
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a new List?

```
var newList = new List<FileInfo>();
newList.Add(latestFile);
IEnumerable<FileInfo> Y = newList;
```